# Use from empty type parameters?

Tags: java, arraylist, types, parameters

I was  recently porting a `Java 7` project down to `Java 6` and I a had some `Arraylist`s being initialized with empty  type parameters.

Of course it gave quite a few errors because of it only being allowed in `Java 7`

So then I was wondering; What use do I get from using empty type parameters?

ex.: `new Arraylist <>();`

Comment: That means the parameter type can be resolved from context. It's just eye candy so that it's faster to write.

Answer (score 0):

It is called generics. It is a compile time concept and is used for type safety. You can take a look about generics in [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/).

If you use

```
List<String> test= new ArrayList<>();
```

i.e. with no generics ON the RHS then it is similar as saying

```
List<String> test= new ArrayList<String>();
```

This is just a feature added in Java 7. As stated previously this being a compile time concept the generics of reference variable is what matters and not of actual object (created with new/RHS)

Comment: This question is about diamond notation, not generics in general.

Comment: In context of `new Arraylist <>();` generics come into picture.

Answer (score 0):

It's called diamond operator and infers the generic type from the left hand side, if possible. Saves you a few keystrokes and was introduced with Java 7 (project coin).